# How'd this hole get here?

Tags: geology

[image]Hiking in a field of boulders along a river canyon in Alabama United states.  Sandstone boulders are 20'-30' (6 to 9 meters) tall.  There are perfectly round holes near the top.  I'm wondering what caused these.  I'm interested in the designs but mainly the perfectly round holes.

---

Comment: Just to clarify (I have no idea, besides animals???), you mean these?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwjPv.jpg

Comment: The big one in the middle looks like tafoni: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafoni

Comment: Mainly the perfectly round one in the upper right.

Comment: thanks for the Tafoni information!  It answers several of my "how'd that happen" moments when out in a boulder field

Comment: it could be chemical erosion, water erosion of even a trace fossil, from just a dark spot on a boulder anything definitive is difficult.